# Grep and Sed Error

Tags: bash, replace, sed, terminal, grep

I want to find a string in some files in a recursive directory and replace it with another string.

The string I want to find is `0x04030000&0xffff0000`.

The string I want to replace is `0x80863a30`.

I tried some examples but `grep` and `sed` cause some errors.

Like `grep` says `0xffff0000 command not found`

Im Using Mac OS X 10.8.5

This was the command I tried and the error I received:

```
localhost:~ User$ grep -rl 0x04030000&0xffff0000 /Users/Niresh/Desktop/TTT | xargs sed -i 's/0x04030000&0xffff0000/0x80863a30/g'
[4] 1166
-bash: 0xffff0000: command not found
grep: warning: recursive search of stdin

[4]+  Stopped                 grep -rl 0x04030000
```

Tried This Command Too But Not Working

```
localhost:~ Niresh$ mkdir TTT
localhost:~ Niresh$ echo "TTT 0x04030000&0xffff0000 bar" > TTT/bar
localhost:~ Niresh$ find TTT -type f -exec sed -i'' -e 's/0x04030000&0xffff0000/0x80863a30/g' {} \;
localhost:~ Niresh$ cat TTT/bar
TTT 0x80863a30 bar
localhost:~ Niresh$ TTT 0x80863a30 bar
-bash: TTT: command not found
```

but I have Tried This Too sed -i'' -e 's/0x04030000&0xffff0000/0x80863a30/g' "Here Was My Path to The Text File"

But The Command Execute Successfully but The Text Remains Still

I Read The Man Page of sed 
It Shows

Bugs Multibyte characters containing a byte with value 0x5C (ASCII `\') may be
     incorrectly treated as line continuation characters in arguments to the
     `a'',`c'' and `i'' commands.  Multibyte characters cannot be used as
     delimiters with the`s'' and ``y'' commands.

BSD                              May 10, 2005

Comment: Show us the command you tried and explain your problem with some examples.

Comment: What OS are you on? You need to provide _some_ information. Is it a binary file, or are you looking through textual hex dumps? If you want to manipulate a binary file, sed and grep may not do it. Awk could not. Perl or other scripting languages could. If you have a binary file and want to get the hex dump, find the thing, do the replacement, and turn the result back into a binary file, this could work. But you may be making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.8.5
I Dont Know How to Get a Hext Dump ?

Comment: Are you actually looking for the *string* `0x04030000&0xffff0000`, or are you really trying to find one set of 4 or 8 bytes and replace it with a different set of 4 bytes?

Comment: im actually looking for the string in a text file and i wanna replace with another string

Comment: Are you having case sensitivity issues?  `F` is not `f`.  I'm guessing here, because you haven't provided enough information.  What about posting the text file to pastebin?

Comment: Okay, with that update, it looks to me like it worked.

Comment: What makes you think that `TTT` is a command?  You *made a directory* named `TTT`.

Comment: TTT is Just The Directory 
With That Update Also It Doesn't Work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep -rl 0x04030000&0xffff0000 /Users/Niresh/Desktop/TTT | xargs sed -i 's/0x04030000\&0xffff0000/0x80863a30/g'

The & Was identified as a special character to fix it just to add a slash \ before the & ( \& ) solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Your `&` is being interpeted by your shell. To avoid this, you should quote your search:

```
grep -rl '0x04030000&0xffff0000' /Users/Niresh/Desktop/TTT | xargs sed -i 's/0x04030000&0xffff0000/0x80863a30/g'
```

Comment: worth nothing that sed will also interpret `&` if you use it in the replacement string.  It's not there now, but it could come up later.

Comment: Doesn't Work :(
I have Tried This Command 
grep -rl '0x04030000&0xffff0000' /Users/Niresh/Desktop/TTT
but Its Not Showing Any files but There are Files Im Sure :)

Comment: @user1862521: I think `-i` is specific to GNU `sed`. That may be why it's not working for you.

Comment: @FatalError, There's a `-i` in [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed) and [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) (derived from FreeBSD), but in older versions it requires an option, hence `-i ''`, and an explicit `-e` before the script part of the command line.

Answer (score 1):

FatalError has already identified the `&` problem in your command line.

Also, this is a bad way to handle files, due to the [Parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problem.  Instead of relying on xargs to capture filenames as the output of grep, you should use `find`.  For example:

```
# find /Users/Niresh/Desktop/TTT -type f \
    -exec grep -q '0x04030000&0xffff0000' {} \; \
    -exec sed -i'' -e 's/0x04030000&0xffff0000/0x80863a30/g' {} \;
```

(split to multiple lines for easier reading.)

The idea here is that `find` will be responsible for your filenames, and will run each of the tools to do (1) the analysis and (2) the modification.  Note that the `grep` here is probably redundant, as `sed` will simply make no changes to files where it doesn't find the search string.

This saves you from issues where there are special characters in your filenames (spaces or newlines or backslashes) which would be misinterpreted by your pipe to `xargs`.

**UPDATE** (per comments):

Works for me:

```
ghoti@mac:~ 507$ mkdir foo
ghoti@mac:~ 508$ echo "foo 0x04030000&0xffff0000 bar" > foo/bar
ghoti@mac:~ 509$ find foo -type f -exec sed -i'' -e 's/0x04030000&0xffff0000/0x80863a30/g' {} \;
ghoti@mac:~ 510$ cat foo/bar
foo 0x80863a30 bar
ghoti@mac:~ 511$
```

If this doesn't work for you, please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19325566/1072112) with the results of your attempts.

Comment: Are you sure you included the `-type f` for find and the `-e` for sed?

Comment: And yet, it does.  See my update.  This is the solution to the problem as described.  If your description needs some work, that'll probably help you get more helpful answers.

Comment: localhost:~ Niresh$ mkdir TTT
localhost:~ Niresh$ echo "TTT 0x04030000&0xffff0000 bar" > TTT/bar
localhost:~ Niresh$ find TTT -type f -exec sed -i'' -e 's/0x04030000&0xffff0000/0x80863a30/g' {} \;
localhost:~ Niresh$ cat TTT/bar
TTT 0x80863a30 bar
localhost:~ Niresh$ TTT 0x80863a30 bar
-bash: TTT: command not found

This Was The Error and i CD Into The /Desktop Folder Where TTT is Located

Comment: I see that you added this to your question too.  Good stuff.  I'm glad it works for you.

Comment: The results you posted in the update to your question demonstrate that it DID work.  You added a line to the end that didn't work of course, but that was not part of your question.

Comment: I Have Checked The Text File Its Still as The Same

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
find  /Users/Niresh/Desktop/TTT -type f -exec sed -i 's/0x04030000&0xffff0000/0x80863a30/g' {} \;
```

This should do the job.

Comment: Tried This Command Error Was 
Several Times This Line
sed: 1: "/Users/Niresh/Desktop/T ...": extra characters at the end of N command